# android, cannot delete SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a dynamic ui where the user can add and remove elements. than onPause I save the current state (strings, ints etc) of the ui on SharedPreferences so the ui can be re=created later in the onResume() call.

```
protected void onResume(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Map<String, String> savedTimers = (Map<String, String>) prefs.getAll();


    if(savedTimers.size() > 0){
        for(int i=0; i<savedTimers.size(); i++){
            // retrieve the info saved on the prefs
            // and do stuff with those (reload a dynamic gui basically)
            ...
            //remove the timer from the prefs
            editor.remove(String.valueOf(i));

        }
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

But it happens that even if the user remove some element from the ui, on sub-sequent calls to onResume will ignore this.

So let's say I have 3 TextViews. Then I close the app and open it again. I have, as expected,  3 TextViews.

BUT if I delete one (or two or all of them) and then close and start the app then I still have three TextViews. The lgos confirm me that it's the onResume the issue.

Is there some error int he logic of my code?

Edit: as per request, here is the logic of the save:

```
protected void onPause(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    for (int i=0; i<container.getChildCount()-1; i++){
        // bla bla bla other code
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), "bla bla bla");
    }   
    editor.commit();
}
```

P.S.
and now I am curious about the comment about the ID from @ksarmalkar

Comment: Show us where you're saving them

Comment: There might be a bug in way you save the preferences. It might be that you are creating with different ID and deleting something totally different. It would be helpful if you post the save logic too.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use your preferences as integer where the value represents the number of textviews?

In your onresume, just ask the number from the preferences.

In that case you don't need to remove, ask for the length or need to retrieve them all.

You might have a conflict too if you declare the Prefs in your onresume, and in your main class. I would not declare it in the onresume at all.

Answer (score 0):

found what the issue was.

I was saving the prefs also in case of screen rotation. So after the rotation I was re-creating the gui from the bundle passed to onRestoreInnstanceState() while the same info was stored in the shared prefs.

Adding a test on isFinishing() on the onPause() alloes to basically skip the code in the onPause() and so no prefs were stored,